# Can I use my personal savings to pay the limited company of which I am the director?

Tags: united-kingdom, savings

I'm an IT contractor (UK). I work and invoice through a limited company. When the pandemic began I was on a voluntary break between contracts. Obviously the market went very quiet.

I decided to continue on a break and use the time to do some training and pursue personal projects. Both work related. In that time I have been living off some savings. I simply transfer the money from a savings account to my personal account as I need it.

My concern is is that there's no financial activity through my business and that's of concern because I hope to get a mortgage within the next couple of years. Given that what I'm actually doing during office hours is work related training and projects, could I actually be paying myself through my business from my savings somehow?

Something like: Ltd company raises an invoice addressed to me, I pay it from savings through my business account.

I realise this would become taxable income where before it wasn't.

Caveat 1: I'm not the sharpest tool in the box when it comes to finances :o) so if this is the dumbest idea you've ever heard please do set me straight.

Caveat 2: If I'm actually suggesting something illegal :-O then rest assured it's my naiveté at work here not any intended malfeasance! (See Caveat 1)

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in the UK, but in the US if you are self employed they don't really ask you for your pay stubs, they ask you for your tax filings over the past 2 years. In the US, an "LLC" and an individual are indistinguishable from a tax perspective, so it doesn't matter how you move money around.

Comment: ***"Something like: Ltd company raises an invoice addressed to me, I pay it from savings through my business account."*** — Can you clarify the money flow in this example? How do you foresee it moving from account to account, all the way from your personal savings to your personal current account?